# Can you extend a HTMLDivElement in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am making a DOM based game for the first time. I would like to extend HTMLDivElement, however in TypeScript, HTMLDivElement is an Interface.

I would like to do this pseudo class:

```
class QuizElement extends HTMLDivElement{

}
```

Sorry if this question is crazy. I am somewhat new to the DOM, and just thought, I can extend any visual class in any other environment so I guess it is do-able here!

Comment: It's not crazy at all. It's actually quite possible, and much better than using document.getElementById to associate a div with a class! You can try it by extending HTMLElement. It works! See more docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements/Custom_Elements_with_Classes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't extend `HTMLDivElement` because it isn't declared as a class. This makes sense, because the underlying native type doesn't make sense to extend.

You have two alternative options.

Option 1: Implements!

Because `HTMLDivElement` is an interface, you can implement it...

```
class QuizElement implements HTMLDivElement {
```

You would have to implement all of the properties and methods of the interface. *You probably don't want to do this*.

Option 2: Delegation.

You can expose the specific properties and methods you want to make available on your `QuizElement` class and then delegate to an actual `HTMLDivElement` instance. Quick example below:

```
class QuizElement {
    private element: HTMLDivElement;

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.element = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById(id);
    }

    set innerHTML(content: string) {
        this.element.innerHTML = content;
    }
}

var quizElement = new QuizElement('quiz');

quizElement.innerHTML = 'Example';
```

Comment: I will go for the second option as it seems much less hassle and cleaner! Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me! :)

Comment: why this answer is at the bottom even if it is accepted as the right answer and it has the most upvotes?

Answer (score 9):

Also you can 'extend' the HTMLDivElement interface with data members if you wish, not by using extends since it is not a class, but by adding it via the interface.  TypeScript interfaces are 'open ended', see page 85 of the spec under 'declaration merging'.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf

for example, the below adds the member 'mydata' of type string to the HTMLDivElement interface.

```
interface HTMLDivElement {

    mydata : string;

}

// now we can assign a value

 var div = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("myDiv"); 

 div.mydata = "test";
```

Comment: `Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'ReactElement'.ts(2440)` what? can you explain more? the link is broken also

Answer (score 5):

Really late to the show, but these days yet another approach is possible. Rather than adding fields to the interface `HTMLDivElement` one can create a new interface like

```
interface QuizElement extends HTMLDivElement {
  quizScore: number;
  ...
}
```

and then create `QuizElement` objects like

```
const quizzi: QuizElement = Object.assign(document.createElement("div"), {
  quizScore: 0,
  ...
});
```

Compared to other proposed approaches, this does not "pollute" `HTMLDivElement` with additional fields in the scope of `QuizElement`.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but apparently it's still not possible to extend HTMLDivElement. A simple way to solve extending a DIV: just use CSS to make a generic HTMLElement behave like a div.

CSS

```
 my-element {
    display:block;
 }
```

Javascript

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
      super()
      this.innerHTML = "I behave exactly like a div"
  }
}

window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

Comment: Having done this, I get an error: "Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call." After adding super() in the constructor, I get the following in the Chrome browser dev tools: "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor".

Comment: Maybe that's a browser setting or a compiler setting? It won't work if you compile to ES5.  If I test this on codesandbox it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-element-example-s8gxh I did have to add the super() call.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best way but it works.

```
function MyElement(){
  var element = document.createElement("div");

  element.viewInner = function(){
    console.log(this, this.innerHTML)
  };

  return element;
}

var test = new MyElement();
test.innerHTML = "Hi";
test.viewInner(); // <div> Hi
```

Comment: This just creates a `div` element, it doesn't extend the native div class to create a custom element.