# extending HTMLElement: Constructor fails when webpack was used

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, web-component

I got the following TypeScript program transpiled to ES5:

File 1:

```
class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

File 2:

```
import {BaseElement} from './BaseElement';

class MyElement extends BaseElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

var el = new MyElement();
```

Putting everything manually within a file, the code works fine and executes in the browser, the HTMLElement is constructed without problems. However, as soon as I pack it via webpack, I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

Without webpack, the following JS code is constructed:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var BaseElement = (function (_super) {
    __extends(BaseElement, _super);
    function BaseElement() {
        _super.call(this);
    }
    return BaseElement;
}(HTMLElement));
var MyElement = (function (_super) {
    __extends(MyElement, _super);
    function MyElement() {
        _super.call(this);
    }
    MyElement.prototype.createdCallback = function () {
        this.innerHTML = "lol";
    };
    return MyElement;
}(BaseElement));
var el = new MyElement();
```

Using webpack, the following code is constructed:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    __webpack_require__(1);
    __webpack_require__(2);

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    "use strict";
    var BaseElement = (function (_super) {
        __extends(BaseElement, _super);
        function BaseElement() {
            _super.call(this);
        }
        return BaseElement;
    }(HTMLElement));
    exports.BaseElement = BaseElement;


/***/ },
/* 2 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    "use strict";
    var BaseElement_1 = __webpack_require__(1);
    var MyElement = (function (_super) {
        __extends(MyElement, _super);
        function MyElement() {
            _super.call(this);
        }
        MyElement.prototype.createdCallback = function () {
            this.innerHTML = "lol";
        };
        return MyElement;
    }(BaseElement_1.BaseElement));
    exports.MyElement = MyElement;
    // TODO: inject
    var p = new MyElement();
/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

Basically, webpack puts any module into a function and maintains an export variable between them, however the construction of HTMLElement fails. Without webpack (code above), it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is transpiling issue. If you are transpiling or using ES5 then you need to  bundle native-shim for browsers with native Web components support.(https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements/blob/master/src/native-shim.js)

If transpiling/using TS then target should be `>=es2015`

> ES5-style classes don't work with native Custom Elements because the   HTMLElement constructor uses the value of `new.target` to look up the custom   element definition for the currently called constructor. `new.target` is only   set when `new` is called and is only propagated via super() calls. super()   is not emulatable in ES5. The pattern of ``` SuperClass.call(this)`` only works   when extending other ES5-style classes, and does not propagate ``` new.target`.

Check the issue discussion https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements/issues/29

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: added `native-shim.js` to my project and it's fix the issue. thanks

Answer (score 20):

> ES5-style classes don't work with native Custom Elements

To do a work around, just change the target in the  tsconfig.json file to es6.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. If you don't need to worry about IE then this is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue with help of this issue - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3225

Basically i installed these 2 plugins via npm and in my WebPack config added those 2 plugins for Babel:

```
use: [
    {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['es2015'],
                // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3225
                plugins: ['transform-custom-element-classes', 'transform-es2015-classes']
            },
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's working without webpack? Running it through the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BaseElement%20extends%20HTMLElement%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyElement%20extends%20BaseElement%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20el%20%3D%20new%20MyElement()%3B) gives the same error as you described (at runtime).

Anyway, you shouldn't be extending the `HTMLElement`.
The `HTMLElement` is actually an interface in typescript, so if anything you should be implementing it as such.
It exists as an object type in the browser, but it hasn't been declared as a typescript class, so typescript isn't able to properly extend it.

For ways around this issue, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823442/can-you-extend-a-htmldivelement-in-typescript).

Comment: Looking at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/customelements/, I guess it is the prefered way to extend an HTMLElement in ES2015 to use Web Components. The problem seems to be how Typescript transpiles such a construct.

Comment: the target option for the playground are set to ES5 automaticly so it throws the same error on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Babel 7 + Webpack 4 config for Web Components:

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-custom-element-classes": "^0.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use:{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                  plugins: [
                    "transform-custom-element-classes",
                    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                  ]
              },
          },
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }
  ]
}
```

Using `transform-es2015-classes` plugin will break the build process when using Babel 7, since `babel-preset-env` already contains it. `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` is necessary for the lifecycle callbacks. Using yearly presets such as `es2015` is deprecated in Babel 7, use `@babel/preset-env` instead.

Comment: Tried this, still get 'Illegal constructor' error though.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Babel 7.6.0**

Personally, the error seems to be gone with these specific devDependencies :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.8"
}
```

And this webpack.config.js :

```
var glob = require('glob');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: glob.sync('./app/scripts/**.js').reduce(function(obj, el){
        obj[path.parse(el).name] = el;
        return obj
    },{}),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/scripts'),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/scripts')
                ],
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/env']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

So basically I'm telling webpack to transpile any .js file in my /app/scripts folder, and save them in /dist/scripts, using babel-loader, with the `@babel/preset-env` package.

**2) Babel 6.*.0**

However, if you're using `@babel/core` `6.*.*`, you might want to check this https://medium.com/@allenhwkim/chrome-browser-custom-element-error-e86db5ae3b8c .  It's quite simple and I already used it successfully before trying to update all my babel packages.

"All" you need to do is `npm install babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes babel-plugin-transform-custom-element-classes --save-dev`, then add them in your webpack.config.js (don't forget to `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015` as well) :

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/scripts')
            ],
            options: {
                presets: ['es2015'],
                plubins: ["transform-custom-element-classes", "transform-es2015-classes"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```