# How can I get Web Components to compile with TypeScript for IE11/Edge/Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, web-component, webpack-4

Having set up a web project to use TypeScript/WebPack I cannot get Google Chrome to run the result:

[image]

The error reads: <kbd>"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function."</kbd>

I learned that [a shim is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037489/extending-htmlelement-constructor-fails-when-webpack-was-used) for transpiling to ES5, but I still can't get this to work. That's probably because I don't want to add a <script> element to the HTML but instead I want to `import "../node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle";` in my `.ts` files.

How can I get this to work without adding <script> elements to my HTML files?

I took my `tsconfig.json` and `webpack.config.js` files from [this tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/).

Comment: Hopefully this helps – https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24556

Comment: It looks like this is making things work for Chrome, but IE11 fails with `customElements is undefined`.

Comment: Found it, thanks to your hint. I'll add the solution here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
npm install @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs --save-dev
```

```
import "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle";
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js';

...
```

As far as I can see, this runs smoothly on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE11.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't include polyfills with your components. Instead, they should be provided by the application consuming the component. I'm not sure if I understood your setup correctly, but _usually_ both `webcomponents-...` and `es5-adapter` are imported using a `<script>` tag (which might be generated by the bundler/compiler) into the main page (which is an HTML page rather than a TS file).

Comment: To give an example for that kind of setup: in my webpack config, there's an `entry` defined for each polyfill, like `{ entry: { polyfills: '@babel/polyfill', 'wc/webcomponents-loader': resolve(__dirname, '../../../node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader'), app: resolve(...) }, ... }`

Comment: Web components are supposed to be served "as-is". There's no compilation step available when including web components. So the transpilation (incl. polyfills) needs to be done in advance, before publishing the web component. That's why it's a `devDependency`.